# Change size layout ImageView when WebView scrolls

Tags: java, android, webview, imageview

I have a project with Android Studio and in Activity I have content html using WebView. The Image should be shown as an ImageView to make it look good. I want to change the height of the ImageView when I scroll the WebView to the bottom and then back to normal size when I scroll back to the top. How can enable it?

Here is my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.demowordpress.app.DetailActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <TextView
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxEms="10"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />
        </LinearLayout>

           </RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/wv"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </WebView>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_retry"
            android:text="try Again"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            ads:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```